# Using classic ASP, is it possible to set the SMTP envelope from address with CDO?

Tags: asp-classic, smtp, messaging

I am sending mail using classic ASP with the CDOSYS objects, but I would like the envelope from address - that is, the one that is specified by MAIL FROM during SMTP - to be set differently to the From header address in the message.

The purpose of this is to implement [VERP](http://cr.yp.to/proto/verp.txt). For example, I would expect the SMTP dialogue to be something like:

```
220 mail.example.com ESMTP
[...]
MAIL FROM: <info+test=example.com@mydomain.test>
250 2.0.0 OK
RCPT TO: <test@example.com>
250 2.0.0 OK
DATA
354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
From: Company1 <info@mydomain.test>
To: test@example.com
[...]
```

In the above example, the envelope from is "info+test=example.com@mydomain.test" but the From header is "info@mydomain.test".

Hope this makes sense. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I got it figured out and I wiresharked it and I see the commands as you want them...

Sorry about the horrible answer I gave you before.  This will do it... it is the "SENDER" that you want for the MAIL FROM: envelope

```
Const cdoSendUsingPort = 2
StrSmartHost = "localhost"

set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

With iConf.Fields 
.item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = cdoSendUsingPort 
.item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = strSmartHost 
.Update 
End With 




With iMsg
Set .Configuration = iConf
.To = "test@example.com"
.Sender = "info+test=example.com@mydomain.test"
.From="Company1 <info@mydomain.test>"
.Subject = "This is a test CDOSYS message (Sent via Port 25)..."
.HTMLBody = strHTML
.Send
End With
```

Comment: I totally misunderstood your question and yes my answer was a mixed bag of ideas that didn't match up... like wires got crossed in my brain when I was typing.  Sorry about that... I now understand what you want to do... it is an interesting question.